# How can i get the location of multiple android phones?

Tags: java, android, location, tracking, bus

I am trying to make a bus tracking app.I want to place some cheap android phones in the busses from my town (they have free wi-fi) and get their location.And then somehow with javascript and google maps show each bus on the map.

Im a beginner btw.

I would like to use JAVA ,Is it possible to get the location of a phone in java and then tell that location to the browser?.

Can you please guide me in the right direction,tell me what to search or what to read? How should i aproach this, if it is at all possible ,Thanks.

Comment: You need a phone, running an app, continually getting its location and then continually (or periodically) sending this information to a server (don't forget that the phone needs to be powered or charged continually, have a data plan to send the information, and I'm not going to go into the legality of leaving phone everywhere, or considering they may be stolen). Then you need another app or web page that can interrogate the server to get the latest information, and display it. Possible, yes. But not easy, especially if you are a beginner.

Comment: Direction guide: spend some time at the local help center to understand why your question doesn't fit here. And honestly : you would need to be a very advanced, disciplined beginner to master such a task.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to send the coordinates of the buses by having an app that reads those coordinates and send it to the server.  The bus tracking app will then read those coordinates and display the markers(locations of the buses) in the map.  You will need Google APIs to translate the coordinates and display those on the map and a server from which the app can read the coordinates.  Those coordinates will have to be refreshed continually, using asynctask or other background network technology along with a handler to re-request the network connection you can achieve this.